# Android - NDK/ARM: float parameters size

Tags: android, java-native-interface, arm

I tried to write a simple ARM function to add two numbers (single precision). This is a part of the code:

```
fmsr s1, r0
fmsr s2, r1
fadds s1, s1, s2
fmrs r0, s1
```

I tested this ARM function in Android using NDK. The prototype of the C function is:

```
jfloat myFunction(jfloat a, jfloat b);
```

The problem is that the result is incorrect.

I used the debuger (DS-5) and It seems that the two numbers that I passed as parameters (the floats a and b) are coded on 64 bits instead of 32 bits. So, the value of **a** was stored in **r0 and r1** and the value of **b** was stored in **r2 and r3**.

Do you have any explanation or a hint to solve the problem?

I've tested the code using Win32 functions (Windows Mobile device) and everything was as I expected.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your Java declaration of this native method?

Comment: C call: float Java_etc_add(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, float a, float b)
{  
    return add(a, b);//add is the ARM function
} Java declaration:  private native float add(float a, float b);